# Get position of mouse and set the position of parent div scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I am trying to set the position of the div on the scroll. This is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vr0kgxL8/). Actually i want to scroll the div on which point i placed my mouse and scroll. On click it is working fine. But on Scroll it is not working.

This is my jquery code

```
$( '#target' ).on( 'wheel', function( e ) {
var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
$( "#target1" ).scrollLeft(x);
$( this ).html(x);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On mousewheel, which you are looking for I guess, you have to use `event.originalEvent`. Mousewheel and DOMMouseScroll need `event.originalEvent` too, since there is no support for wheel event.

use `event.originalEvent.pageX`

```js
$( '#target' ).on( 'mousewheel', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = e.originalEvent.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft;
    $( "#target1" ).scrollLeft(x);
    console.log(e.originalEvent.pageX, e.target.offsetLeft);
    $( this ).html(x);
});

$( '#target' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    $( "#target1" ).scrollLeft(x);
    console.log(e.pageX, this.offsetLeft);
    $( this ).html(x);
});
```

```css
body {
    padding:50px;
}

#target {
    background-color:gray;
    width:500px;
    height:240px;
    padding-top:50px;
    font-size:larger;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
    
}

#target1{
  overflow-x: scroll;
   width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target1">
<div id="target"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfect Sir! Let me test this on my application. So this was just about the `originalEvent`. ?

Comment: Yes, if you have tried to do it with `mousewheel` event ;]

Comment: actually i dont know but mousewheel was not working in my app. so i used on wheel .

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get mouse current position on scroll, so I created a global variable to store it `xMousePos`, check this fiddle:

```js
var xMousePos = 0;
var yMousePos = 0;

$("#target1").scroll(function(e) {
  var tg1 = $(this);
  var tg = tg1.children(0);
  var x = xMousePos;
  //console.log("Scroll:"+xMousePos);
  $(this).scrollLeft(x);
  $("#target1").children(0).html(x);
});

$("#target1").mousemove(function(event) {
  xMousePos = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  yMousePos = event.pageY - this.offsetLeft;
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

#target {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 500px;
  height: 240px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

#target1 {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target1">
  <div id="target"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Like your idea but  i think @Yordan solution was the best one using only `originalEvent`.

Comment: @adeel Yea, I liked it too, I did not know the `.originalEvent`